# Replace the matched group with spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is the contents of the `<style>` tag of my HTML document:

```html
<style>
        a:link { color: blue; }
  a:link:hover { color: red;  }
</style>
```

As you see rules are aligned by the opening brace.

Now I need to to remove the `:link` part from the second rule and keep the alignment in tact.

Here is what I have:

```js
function getStyleAndChangeIt() {
  let style = document.querySelector('style').innerText;
  style = style.replace(/(a)(?::link)(:hover|:focus|:active)/g, '$1$2');
  return style;
}
```

It doesn't solve the task, of course. It simply removes the `:link` part **without** keeping the alignment in tact.

So how to change it so that it will work exactly as I want it? Cheers.

It is actually necessary to replace the `:link` part with spaces and place these spaces before `a`, but I don't know how.

edit:

In other words, the desired output is:

```
   a:link { color: blue; }
  a:hover { color: red;  }
```

Comment: (Why is the alignment needed? CSS mostly ignores white-space)

Comment: @evolutionxbox The contents of the `style` tag will be placed inside `pre`. This is for a file that is used for educational purposes. To show the order in which `link`, `visited`, `hover`, `active`, and `focus` pseudo-classes (and their combinations) must be located.

Comment: Oh cool. If it's placed within a pre element, why is it inside a style element? (I'm actually just interested)

Comment: @evolutionxbox Because the `pre` should show the styles that are currently used in this exact document. :) This is really not so easy to describe here because there are some additioanal steps. If you are really interested, I will post the final file at Pastebin when it will be finished.

Comment: If you know the length of the line before replacement what about: `styleLine.padStart(styleLineLength, ' ')`?

Comment: May you share the output you want after the code has been run?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I added the desired output to the question. It seems my statement _"It is actually necessary to replace the :link part with spaces"_ was wrong.

Comment: Okay then... i'lll edit my code @jsv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add 5 spaces (the length of `:link`) before `$1` in the substitution argument, and use

```js
const text = `<style>
        a:link { color: blue; }
  a:link:hover { color: red;  }
</style>`;
console.log(text.replace(/(a):link(:(?:hover|focus|active))/g, "     $1$2"));
```

Note you do not need a non-capturing group in `(?::link)`, it is the same as `:link`. You only need the group if you intend to use alternation or quantify the group pattern sequence.

Answer (score 0):

All the things I changed are comments in the function.

```js
function getStyleAndChangeIt() {
  // I wasn't able to make the snippet without changing the style tag, but you should change it back in your code
  // I also had to use innerHTML not innerText, because of extra white spaces. That's why the spacing was removed.

  let style = document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML;
  style = style.replace(/(a)(?::link)(:hover|:active|:focus)/gm, '$1$2');

  // since you know a is meant to be the first letter no need to put it in a group
  // I also removed the colon in front of the pseudo-classes since they all have it

  return style;
}

console.log(getStyleAndChangeIt())
```

```html
<pre>        
        a:link { color: blue; }
  a:link:hover { color: red;  }
</pre>
```

Comment: This won't work for a general case? unless the OP only cares about links

Comment: Alright, let me change the code then. I thought he only cared about the links. My bad though

Comment: May you also use the same indenting as in the question? (I swapped the div for a pre, to match what the OP was asking for)

Comment: (btw the output `a :hover` is not equivalent to `a:hover`)

Comment: The OP said its "It is actually necessary to replace the :link part with spaces and place these spaces before a, but I don't know how." The last part of the question

Comment: oh strange. That completely changes the selector and could make it invalid...

Comment: Yeah LOL... I guess it's cause the OP wants to specify where the code was changed